# Validation failed: [Object] code has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I newbie in FactoryGirl.

I have a lot of FactoryGirl models. They are related each other.

I declared the following models as below:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :org_plan_years
  has_many :subscribers
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end

class OrgPlanYear < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :coverages
end

class Coverage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber
  belongs_to :org_plan_year
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

And define FactoryGirl:

**factories/organizations.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization_benefit, class Organization do
    name 'Benefit'
    organization_code '2341'
  end
end
```

**factories/subscribers.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscriber_875450002, class: Subscriber do
    association :organization, factory: :organization_benefit
    ssn 875450002
  end
end
```

**factories/org_plan_years.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :org_plan_year_benefit, class: OrgPlanYear do
    association :organization, factory: :organization_benefit
    name 'First OPY'
  end
end
```

**factories/coverages.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :coverage_1, class: Coverage do
    association :subscriber,    factory: :subscriber_875450002
    association :org_plan_year, factory: :org_plan_year_benefit
  end
end
```

Sample of a test:

```
it 'test' do
  FactoryGirl.create(:coverage_1)
end
```

When I run my test, I get an error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Organization code has already been taken
```

I think, the problem is caused because I set up organization several times in factories, but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Are these really the complete definitions of your models? The error message you shared would suggest that there is more to them, such as validations. Also, what is the intent of your `:coverage_1` factory in terms of organization uniqueness, given that the direct and indirect associations result in the creation of two organizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that :organization_benefit factory should created a new Benefit with a unique organization_code value. You can do this using FactoryGirl sequences. Can you try this code?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization_benefit, class Organization do
    name 'Benefit'
    sequence(:organization_code) {|n| 100 + n }
  end
end
```

Comment: You understood me wrong. Your solution always create organization with new :organization_code. For example, I want create 2 subscribers for one organization. First subscriber was created good, but next don't, because organization with these params was created before.

Comment: To create 2 subscribers for one organization try this code:
    org = create(:organization_benefit)
    subscriber1 = create(:subscriber_875450002, organization: org)
    subscriber2 = create(:subscriber_875450002, organization: org)